# Recurrence question on Binary strings

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $B_n$ be the set of binary strings of length $n$ such that:

1. Every even length block of $0's$ is followed exactly by $1$, and
2. Every odd length block of $0's$ is followed exactly by $11$ (exactly two 1's)

and a block is a substring of non-zero length of either $0's$ or $1's$.

Let $b_n$ be the cardinality of $B_n$. How can I show that 
 $$b_n=b_{n-2}+2b_{n-3}$$ where $b_0=b_1=b_2=1$ and $b_3=3$.

I tried to come up with the sets $B_3$ and $B_5$ which are $$B_3=\{001,011,101\}$$ and $$B_5=\{00101,10101,11001,11011,11101\}.$$ I know I have to use rule of sum (and/or maybe bijection) but I am having some troubles defining the sets by looking at the trivial case that I found. Any help on how to show this recurrence will be highly appreciated

Comment: It seems there is another condition that there must be at least one $0$ in the string.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Either you should allow all 1s, in which case, $b_3 = 4$,  or, if angryavian's proposal that there must be at least one 0 is right, then $b_0 = b_1 = 0$. Either way the recurrence relation doesn't hold for $n=3$.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, it does say specifically but i "think" that should follow from the definition of a block that I just added.

Comment: @jaynot: your definition of a block clarifies rule 1, but it doesn't determine whether angryavian's condition is required to hold.

Comment: @Jaynot I don't think that resolves anything. Your definitions still allow for all-$1$s strings, since rule 1 holds vacuously (there are no even length blocks of $0$s).

Comment: Shouldn't $B_5$ include $00001$ as well?  Why does it include $11101$ because the odd length block of $0$ has one $1$ after it?  $10101$ has the same question.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are right. @RossMillikan You are right too and that clearly disproves the recurrence relation. I am solving past questions for an upcoming exam this week, I am going to talk the Prof to see what is going on here and update it here whatever he says. Thanks guys.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, for your added comment

Answer (score 0):

I think the argument for the recurrence assumes the string must start with $0$.  Then an acceptable string of length $n$ can come from a string of length $n-2$ which you put $00$ in front of or a string of length $n-3$ that you put $001$ or $011$ in front of.  That gives the recurrence $b_n=b_{n-2}+2b_{n-3}$ with $$B_3=\{001,011\}\\ B_4=\emptyset\\B_5=\{00001,00011\}\\ B_6=\{001001,001011,011001,011011\}$$